# Calculate object distance from camera with Tenserflow in Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

```
final List<ObjectionDetector.Recognition> mappedRecognitions = new LinkedList<>();

for (final ObjectionDetector.Recognition result : results) 
{
  final RectF location = result.getLocation();
}
```

Comment: Please Help me to find out distance calculation of the object from the camera with tenserflow in android

Comment: Any solution for this?